# Prevent JS code to run, before function has ended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't wrap my head around this one? 
**WHY IS IT THAT MY:** 
.each loop runs right through even though I'm stalling things inside by 1000ms per loop?

**The problem** is that the window.location.href command runs **TO EARLY** before the setTimeout **has finished**? Same for the stopload() function which is also ended to early? I have seen something about recursive setTimeout functions is that what is needed here and how do I implement that?

```
function shop(clickedButton)
{
  var buttonvalue = $(clickedButton).val();
  startLoad();
  pdel = 1000;

  $("input:submit[value='buy']").each(function(index)
  {
    if(index != 1)
    {

       $("#backgroundPopup").text(index);
       var submithing = this;  
       setTimeout(function(){ clicksubmitbutton(submithing); },pdel);
       pdel += 1000;
    }                      
  });   

  stopLoad();

  if(buttonvalue == "1")
  {
     window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
  else
  {
     window.location.href = 'http://my.url';
  }
```

}

Comment: `setTimeout` does not stall anything. You just tell JavaScript do execute something in the future, *after* the current script execution terminated. If you want to execute something after the timeout, you have to put it in / call from the timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has no notion of a sleep, or stall.  Execution continues right past a `setTimeout` call.  This function simply schedules a function to be run after the given number of milliseconds.

In order to get your desired behavior, you need to call the next iteration in the `setTimeout` callback function.

Something like:

```
function submitTheThing(index) {
    if (done) { //some logic
        return;
    }

    // do something

    setTimeout(function() { submitTheThing(index+1); }, 1000);
}
```